# How to Extract Content From HTML

Tags: android, html, jsoup, selector

I have HTML as string and i want to extract just "post_titles" from it. this is the HTML string:

```
<div class="hidden" id="inline_49">
<div class="post_title">Single parenting</div>
<div class="post_name">single-parenting</div>
<div class="post_author">90307285</div>
<div class="comment_status">open</div>
<div class="ping_status">open</div>
<div class="_status">publish</div>
<div class="jj">20</div>
<div class="mm">07</div>
<div class="aa">2015</div>
<div class="hh">00</div>
<div class="mn">52</div>
<div class="ss">33</div>
```

This has the post title as "Single parenting" which is what i want to extract. This is what i am using :

```
Elements link = doc.select("div[class=post_title]");
String title = link.text();
```

But this is giving a blank string. I also tried:

```
Elements link = doc.select("div[id=inline_49]").select("div[class=post_title]");
String title = link.text();
```

This is also giving a blank string. Please help me what selector exactly I need to use to extract the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include a cookie in your request. 
Check this Java code:

```
try {

            String url = "https://ssblecturate.wordpress.com/wp-login.php";

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("log", "your_login_here") // your wordpress login
                    .data("pwd", "your_password_here") // your wordpress password
                    .data("rememberme", "forever")
                    .data("wp-submit", "Log In")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();

            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://ssblecturate.wordpress.com/wp-admin/edit.php")
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .get();

            Element titleElement= document.select("div[class=post_title]").first();
            System.out.println(titleElement.text());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine. now i see what the problem was. in order to access the html contents from that page (https://ssblecturate.wordpress.com/wp-login.php) i was required to give login information, that is why it was returning null strings.

Comment: i also want to ask whether it is good practice to have my login information (id and password) in my code. Will the users be capable to use that information and misuse my blog website?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but make sure your HTML text is well formatted in the String :

```
String html = "<div class=\"hidden\" id=\"inline_49\">" +
            "<div class=\"post_title\">Single parenting</div>" +
            "<div class=\"post_name\">single-parenting</div>" +
            "<div class=\"post_author\">90307285</div>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements divElements = document.select("div");
for(Element div : divElements) {
    if(div.attr("class").equals("post_title")) {
       System.out.println(div.ownText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still giving an empty string. the logcat gives an error: Invalid cookie header. Dont know if it has got to do something with it.

Comment: it is a free wordpress blog website:  https://ssblecturate.wordpress.com/. This page does not show all posts at a time (only shows like 7, when you scroll down more posts become visible). So i use a different address which shows all posts together: https://ssblecturate.wordpress.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post

Answer (score 1):

Updated !
Hope It works for you :

```
//Get div tag with class name is 'post_title'

Document doc;
    try {
        File input = new File("D:\\JAVA\\J2EE\\Bin\\Bin\\Project\\xml\\src\\demo\\index.html");
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
        //Get div tag with class name is 'post_title'
        Element element = doc.select("div.post_title").first();
        System.out.println(element.html());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: this is giving null pointer exception at element.html(); line.

Comment: I've also tried out this code (from a `String`, not from a file), and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in a String, you can try with `regExp`.

This regex means "everything between  with class post_title (not exactly but yes for your sample).

```
String exp = "<div class=\"post_title\">([^<]*)</div>"
```

You should be able to get the content with:

```
String post_title = Pattern.compile(exp).matcher(yourString).group(1);
```

NOTE: I guess your post_title does not contain "<"... This should indeed generate an XML structure error.